# Getting 'Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component' before useEffect cleanup function executes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the warning "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" before the useEffect cleanup function is called.

This code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
   doFetch();
   return () => { console.log('useEffect cleanup'); };
}, []);

const doFetch = async () => {
   const response = await fetchAsync(...);
   console.log('about to set state');
   setData(response.data);
   console.log('did set state');
};
```

produces the console output:

```
about to set state
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
did set state
useEffect cleanup
```

I would think that my cleanup function would execute before the component unmounts and thus before the warning, but it's executing after the warning. Because of that, I can't get the warning to go away by properly canceling the asynchronous task (which I've tried). How can I get this warning to go away?

If it makes any difference, the component is being mounted and unmounted inside of a unit test using ReactDOM.render() and ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(). The fetchAsync function is being stubbed out with

```
const stub = sinon.stub(..., fetchAsync);
stub.returns(Promise.resolve({status: 200, data: {});
```

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but you need to handle errors from `doFetch`. Otherwise, if the fetch fails, you'll get "Unhandled rejection" errors.

Comment: Yep, I took it out for simplicity but I do handle it in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`

Read more here

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect

Comment: *"Use useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect'"* Say **why**. Answers should be complete even if the link were to disappear.